# Facebook SDK PHP inside a plugin

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, wordpress

I am getting this error:

`Graph returned an error: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this actionPosted with id: 136766596799963`

My WP plugin has this structure:

```
myplugin/
    |-css/
    |-images/
    |-includes/
        data-processing.php
    |-js/
    |-src/
        |-facebook-sdk-v5/
            autoload.php + other fb sdk files and directories
    myplugin.php
```

In myplugin.php I have this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
Plugin Name: MY PLUGIN
*/

/************************
* global variables
************************/

$plugin_prefix  = 'MYPLUGIN_';
$plugin_name    = 'MYPLUGIN';

/************************
* includes
************************/

// Facebook SDK
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . ('/src/facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php');

include_once dirname(__FILE__) . ('/includes/data-processing.php');
```

In my data-processing.php file I have this:

```
<?php
/************************
* main plugin code 
************************/

use Facebook\FacebookRequest;


class Myplg {

    public $options;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->options = get_option('cstm_myplugin_plugin_options');
        $this->register_settings_and_fields();
    }

    public static function add_menu_page()
    {
        $page_title = 'MY PLUGIN';
        $menu_title = 'MY PLUGIN';
        $capability = 'administrator';
        $menu_slug  = __FILE__;
        $function   = array('Myplugin', 'display_options_page');
        $icon_url   = plugins_url( '../images/ico_myplugin.png' , __FILE__ );
        $position   = 3;
        add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position );
    }

    public function display_options_page()
    {

        $plugin_options = get_option('cstm_myplg_plugin_options');

        $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
            'app_id' => '918761491987952';
            'app_secret' => 'rtaas683asdeefb3d78cas3cb849888dfsdf9b3';
            'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
        ]);

        $access_token = 'CA9fdidTJJ9cBAOCyWA23TqAna9eGZCsZBZBvCYhgG2MZB5Bx15d8uhNaILwUJ6HFMSgua7Q4MRZB3ZAHi3o84UDX3qUrLJ5Ie4WLaB5YhyRgTrZCIu1LGLOL3qfKoANNykPhuM24g82bWBN52lbpdoedya1POmBTyZBZB2FV908jlxxFp5aFU9za1IJ4juGWAKpM4e37MusVI0ZA3uvDWEfsRd';

        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($access_token);

        //GET USER NAME
        try {
          $response = $fb->get('/me');
          $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
          // When Graph returns an error
          echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
          // When validation fails or other local issues
          echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
        }

        echo 'Logged in as ' . $userNode->getName(); // works ;)

        //POST A TEST MESSAGE ON A PAGE WALL
        $linkData = [
            'link'    => 'http://www.example.com',
            'message' => 'Test message',
        ];

        try {
          // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
          $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $access_token);
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
          echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          //exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
          echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          //exit;
        }

        $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

        echo 'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id']; // doesn't work ;(


} // END OF CLASS

add_action('admin_menu', function() {
    Myplg::add_menu_page();
});

add_action('admin_init', function() {
    new Myplg();
});
```

So, the result is that I can get the name of the user as you can see, but I am unable to post a message on the facebook page wall.

I am getting this:

`Logged in as john doeGraph returned an error: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this actionPosted with id: 136766596799963`

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: How can I not auhtorized the app if I am the creator and superadmin. I am logged in into FB when trying the code, etc. I don't get it.

Comment: I think even if you are the creator of an app, you still have to grant it the permission to post in your name. Did that special dialog yet pop up?

Comment: @flomei no, how to initiate it?

Comment: Normally that pops up, when you first use an app and grant it access to your account.

Comment: Solved. The problem was with the wordpress url